# When a TestMethod fails repeat once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

I'm writing coded UI test's for an ASP.NET MVC web application. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Basically I have a bunch of test methods like below:

[image]

I use a ordered test file to run all of them at once in the order I would like.

The problem is that the way the tests work is that if one test fails, it is marked as ref/failed in the output, and often a test will work if I run it again. **I want to be able to set my ordered test to run and if a test method fails it will automatically try to run that test method one more time**.

How do I do this? I was thinking of putting an `if` statement at the end of each test method, like:

```
if(TestFailed) {
    RecallTest();
}
```

I would use some sort of counter, but how do I write the above in a coded UI test?

Comment: When a test fails, what error does it typically give? If the problem lies with your test (such as a test trying to interact with a control before the control is rendered), you're probably better off modifying the test to be more reliable than just rerunning. That way you won't mask any real errors.

Comment: The test is very reliable its just every now and then I get a timeout error or something like that, its just a smoke test so im not worried about that kind of error but the test would have passed if I run it again.

Comment: In the question you say that the test is not reliable because it sometimes fails. What you describe is a fault in the application or in the test suite. Ignoring the fault, hiding it and hoping it goes away invites the fault to reappear when real users (paying customers) are using the application.

Comment: this is just a preliminary smoke test to test the basics of the site, smaller errors will be looked for in further on testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can handle this. The most obvious is something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void myTestMethod()
{
    int iteration = 0;
    if (iteration < 2)
    {
       try
       {
           // the usual test code goes here
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
            // handles any exception kind
            iteration++;
            myTestMethod(); 
       }
    }
}
```

This will recursively call the test method only if the method fails. You can set it to catch any exception (Exception) or to catch specific exceptions only - just change the exception kind in the catch block.

This is typically discouraged in CodedUI tests because it can interact badly with the test runner's built in exception reporting (I'd recommend looking at adding logging to report that you got a failure). It will give you the one-time only rerun, however (Caveat: I haven't actually tried this myself - you might need to tweak the code to ensure that your test cleanup occurs depending on your test code).

Comment: It just ends up in an endless cycle performing the same method over and over again.

Comment: `iteration` should be incremented outside the `try...catch` and I would say the code "iteratively calls the test method" rather than "recursively".

Comment: The `if` might be better if changed to a `while`.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - that's what I get for quickly bashing out something that could provide what the OP wants as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the playback error handling:

```
 Playback.PlaybackError += Playback_PlaybackError;
```

This way you can register an event handler that is called every time the playback encounters an error.

In the event handling method you can tell the playback to repeat the action that threw the error:

```
static void Playback_PlaybackError(object sender, PlaybackErrorEventArgs e)
{                              
    e.Result = PlaybackErrorOptions.Retry;
}
```

A counter can be added to prevent an endless loop of error and retry.